# What request headers must be sent to a server for it to serve you a non-cached response

Tags: node.js, caching, https, cloudflare, cache-control

At https://kith.com/products.json a certain response header is sent notifying me that I am accessing cached data `x-cache: hit, client` I want to bypass this and receive the response header `x-cache: miss`

I have passed in the request headers

```
 'cache-control': 'no-store',
 'pragma': 'no-cache'
```

Here is the curl

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://kith.com/products.json' \
--header 'Cache-Control:  no-store' \
--header 'Pragma: no-cache'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that any cache-related headers sent by the client with a request may not be respected by the server, although any well-behaved proxy (e.g. CloudFlare in this case) should act reasonably.

I tried your test request and got `x-cache: hit, server`. I may have got a cache miss the first time, but that happened in my browser and the network log got cleared (subsequently fetching favicon.ico).

I don't believe there's any way you can force a `x-cache: miss` if the servers are configured to cache certain resources for a certain duration.

Here's the [CloudFlare Cache-Control info](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003206852-Understanding-Origin-Cache-Control#h_7689381961311546894852956) page. Note that it's written from the perspective of devs working on the origin server and configuring CloudFlare, and not users/clients making requests.

Edit: I just realized that the domain `kith.com` can be a very high traffic site. I would consider any way of bypassing the cache from the client as a bug on the server-side that would work against them for performance.

Comment: How do they recognize whether to send the user-agent a cached response or one from origin? I know there has to be a way to let the server know to send from origin meaning x-cache:miss because like you said it happened the first time.

Comment: Your client (curl, browser, etc) is never talking to the origin server, we communicate with the CloudFlare proxy servers that communicate with the origin servers. CloudFlare's primary purpose is to cache request/responses to reduce load (for better performance) for the servers behind them.

I said it 'might' have happened the first time--I didn't see the response headers. In order for it to be a `x-cache: miss` the no one on the internet would have had to make a request for 'products.json' that got routed to a particular CloudFlare server for a caching period.

Comment: What I mean is, the first time you got x-cache:miss what was the indicator that told the proxy server to serve you a non cached response.

Comment: The order things happen is like this: 1 client makes request to CF proxy; 2 CF proxy decides whether to serve cached response, if so returns it done; otherwise 3 CF proxy makes request (with it's own request headers, not exactly copied from client) to origin server; 4 origin server responds to CF proxy; 5 CF proxy caches response; 6 CF proxy returns response to client.

The `x-cache: miss` is a response header from the CF proxy to the client which is purely informational saying what happened, it had no control effect.

Comment: x-cache:miss means the proxy server had to make a request to origin and served an up to date to the second response, I understand that it is a response header but what I’m trying to figure out is what triggers the proxy server to make a request to origin.

Comment: What triggers that is if nobody on the internet made a request for 'products.json' for a while, then you are the first person to next make a request, that will happen. It's not about what you're doing on the client. It's about what requests (from anywhere on the internet) is happening on the CF proxy server.

Comment: `x-cache: miss` means the data is fresh. `x-cache: hit, server` means that it's as fresh as you're going to get from Kith/CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a horrible hack but testing on the browser it does seem to produce cache misses. 
GET protocol allows a query string which cloudflare must assume will produce different results. However if you send along a query string that your target will ignore such as `https://kith.com/products.json?a=a` and then `https://kith.com/products.json?b=b` it will trigger a cache miss but kith.com will still serve the same file.

Comment: I’ve tried this before I opened the SO question. It definitely is interesting but it doesn’t give x-cache:miss every time it’s only every so often I tested a lot.

Comment: I need a way to get x-cache:miss every time I don’t believe it has anything to do with query string because I don’t think kith caches based on query string.

Comment: You can't guarantee `x-cache: miss` because the purpose of the cache is to avoid missing as much as possible. Likewise, you aren't the only user of the site so someone else might get the cache miss.

Comment: I have seen cache bypass on cloudflare before, I don’t think it’s impossible to trick cloudflare into serving from origin every time.

Comment: yes. though it will depend on the settings setup by kith.com. I'd almost wonder if it would make more sense to reach out to them directly for what you want instead of fighting cloudflare for it though

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to force any server to bypass the website owner's caching mechanisms. Cacheing at the server is under the control of the website owner and they have a wide range of discretion on how chacheing is configured. If they so choose they can ignore any headers and/or query strings on incoming requests, then any attempt by you to force a cache miss will not work.

Having said that, if the website owner has set up rules for cacheing which allow certain types of request to bypass the cache, then you may be able to take advantage of this *even if you are not really using that type of request*. Putting spurious GET query strings on the URL is a case in point. Another often-used ruse is to submit a POST request instead of GET - most websites treat POST messages as incoming data-bearing messages and forward them to the servers, and most servers will process a POST request as a GET if they are not expecting any form submission. But bear in mind this is actually an abuse of the web site: the owner is using cacheing to try to reduce the load on the main servers, so attempts to bypass the cache are effectively a finger in the eye and a bit of an insult for the website owner, who is entitled to be offended.

If you *really* need to have access to the origin version of the website data, for some good and serious purpose, you should perhaps contact the owner to find out if they would be prepared to give you access (perhaps via a non-public URL) to the original server version of the data, but you will need to make a good case and I suspect you may have a hard time convincing them.

Comment: Tried post request, query strings, changing request headers. None of it works x-cache:miss only comes sporadically. I dont think this is about being malicious and making millions of requests to origin with cache bypass its more of a learning experience and seeing if its even possible.

Comment: I think using POST you do get past the `X-Edge-Cache` which I presume is the cache controlled by CloudFlare - that always (in my tests) reports `MISS`. Having got through to the server, though, it may be that there is another server-level cache, and at that point the server ignores the distinction between GET and POST, so delivers from the cache. Still, you may be getting a more up-to-date copy than you would with GET.